# How WebFault Annotation at JAX-WS Works?

Tags: java, web-services

I have implemented throwing an exception at Java Web Services. My class is as follows:

```
@WebFault(faultBean = "com.au.ex.FaultBean", targetNamespace =
"something_here") public class Ex extends Exception {
  ... 
}
```

If I don't define *targetNamespace* it throws **null pointer exception** at **Soap UI**.

My question is: ***should I define targetNamespace and how can I retrieve default targetNamespace***?

**PS:** If I define the same namespace with web services' name space it still throws an exception. If I define anything else it works?

Any ideas?

Comment: I am suspicious about that: it makes xml name conflict to use same targetNamespace.

Answer (score 0):

targetNamespace:
Specifies the XML namespace of the WSDL and XML elements generated from the Web service. The default value is the namespace mapped from the package name containing the Web service. (String)

sound like you don't *need* a namespace unless dealing with XML or WSDL...